# crawling dynamic content using ruby

Tags: ruby, web-crawler, dynamic-content

I am using ruby gems (nokogiri & mechanize) to make a crawler for a website but this website contains bootstrap modals (popup windows) that's generated dynamically on button click.

this content (of modal) shows up on button click that uses a "get" method on some URL.

I am getting the response by crawling the URL associated with the button 
but I am just getting the same page source.

how could I get the content of that dynamic content using "ruby" ?

Comment: Please post some code we can actually assist with because right now it is nearly impossible to help since we have no idea what you are actually doing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That modal you're describing, with high probability is rendered with a Js. So what you're looking for is not possible, because mentioned libs do not execute Js.

In order to parse pages whose content is Js dependent, you should use other tools, e.g.  [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)